# why store completed transaction for in app purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I've set up a *non-consumable* in app purchase for may app, it all works well except i haven't yet decided on the correct RestoreTransaction procedure.

Apple suggest storing a list of completed transactions in `NSUserDefaults`, but why?

If the customer resets the device then surely this list is lost so its a non starter?

Can anyone tell me from their experience, if I do need to list completed items and if I need to validate the receipt with apple for *non-consumable* purchase.

I can't see why either of these should be done for *non-consumable* products.

Doesn't Apple verify the purchase from OriginalTransaction when restoreCompletedTransactions is called?

Comment: You need to provide a "restore purchases" button for non-consumable purchases, so it doesn't matter if the NSUserDefaults is reset

Comment: With respect that wasn't my question. I have provided a restore button but my question was why provide anything other than the restoreCompletedTransaction call which requests the ProductID from Apple; if Apple see that this was previously purchased then the customer is not charged again.

Comment: Ok.  You don't need to store the transaction data, you do need to store the fact that the purchase was made and therefor "unlock" the feature. When you call restoreCompletedTransacrion you get the transaction details again.  If the user attempts the purchase again this is when they are told that they won't be charged. Receipt validation offers you some opportunity to thwart jailbreak pirates who try to unlock your purchases without actually purchasing.

Comment: Thank you Paul! One thing I failed to mention is its Apple hosted content so would I be correct in saying that all I need to do here is provide the restoreCompletedTransaction call via the restore button? and as there is nothing to unlock I wont need to verify their receipt? - thanks for your time!

Comment: Forgot to mention above. I want to allow them to download only a single product at a time so I just call for the SKDownload with ProductID as I would with a normal purchase?